# Retaining "height" declaration in jQuery after an Ajax call (dropdown selection loads product data, resets height on other page elements)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jQuery setting a height on product descriptions, this can be seen here:

https://www.gabbyandlaird.com/product/truition-products/truition-healthy-weight-loss-pack

The code I'm using to achieve this is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var $dscr = $('.commerce-product-field-field-long-description'),
    $switch = $('#toggle'),
    $initHeight = 70; // Initial height

$dscr.each(function() {
    $.data(this, "realHeight", $(this).height());    // Create new property realHeight
    }).css({ overflow: "hidden", height: $initHeight + 'px' });

$switch.toggle(function() {
      $dscr.animate({ height: $dscr.data("realHeight") }, 200);
      $switch.html("- Read More").toggleClass('toggled');

    }, function() {
        $dscr.animate({ height: $initHeight}, 200);
        $switch.html("+ Read More").toggleClass();
    });
});
```

I am by no means a Javascript expert (or even an amateur for that matter). My knowledge of jQuery is fairly limited, so I'm not sure what needs to be changed above so that when the dropdown selection reloads the data on the page, I don't lose the height value on the "Read More" section of the product description. Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as per your code above it looks you are doing everything when the document is ready.
here is what you can do.

```
var initialHeight = function(){
    // you height initialization code here
}

$(function () {
    $(document).ready(initialHeight); // initializes the height on document ready         
    $("#yourSelectBox").change(initialHeight); // initializes the height on combobox selection change

});
```

hope this helps.